# Resolve circle vs circle 2d collisions

Tags: c#, math, 2d, game-physics, collision

i am trying to build a simple 2d physics engine for practice , iam having trouble with collision resolution.

```
  public static void OnColision(RigidBody a, RigidBody b, float depth)
        {
            Vec2 CNormal = new Vec2(b.Position - a.Position);
            CNormal = VectorMath.Normalize(CNormal);
            a.ApplyForce(new Vec2(-CNormal.X * depth, -CNormal.Y * depth));
            b.ApplyForce(new Vec2(CNormal.X * depth, CNormal.Y * depth));
        }
```

atm i am using this to resolve the collisions ( the detection works fine) , but using this works like a spring , they act more like soft bodies then rigid ones. i have tried a formula i fount online which is

```
float distance = VectorMath.Distance(a.Position, b.Position);
float nx = (b.Position.X - a.Position.X) / distance;
float ny = (b.Position.Y - a.Position.Y) / distance;

float impulse = 2 * (a.Velocity.X * nx + a.Velocity.Y * ny - b.Velocity.X * nx - b.Velocity.Y * ny) / (a.Mass + b.Mass);

float vx1 = a.Velocity.X - impulse * b.Mass * nx;
float vy1 = a.Velocity.Y - impulse * b.Mass * ny;
float vx2 = b.Velocity.X + impulse * a.Mass * nx;
float vy2 = b.Velocity.Y + impulse * a.Mass * ny;

a.Velocity = new Vec2(vx1, vy1); 
b.Velocity = new Vec2(vx2, vy2);
```

but it was still very glitchey and even worse then the first one, i would like it if someone could give me the right way to resolve the collision in a realistic way and also explain if possible , thanks alot

Comment: I don't really understand what seems to be different to what you expect? What exactly do you mean by "they behave more like soft bodies"?

Comment: when they collide they first overlap and only then they seperate , in my resolution method i apply the force on the depth , so lets say both objects move at a speed of 10 , the first frame they overlap they will keep moving the same direction just in 10 - depth speed, it takes sevral frames to resolve , which causes a sim that looks like a soft body

Comment: Perhaps you prefer [these formulas for elastic 2D collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects)

Comment: If you've tied collision to framerate (e.g. you check or collision at each frame, rather than knowing when they'll collide because you know the forces involved, so you know the _time_ they collide) and you don't want them to overlap, you'll have to change your collision detection to whether the distance between their centers is `<= r1 + r2 + some_small_value` rather than `<= r1 + r2`, to compensate for the fact that the collision is virtually guaranteed to occur between frames.

Comment: Don't simulate instances in time (time at frame A, B, C...) time is a continuum between frames., You need to move both objects (back in time between prev frame and current) to point of collision (just touching) calculate the new vectors and move both object forward (in time to current frame). If you have many objects that can collide over the time of 1 frame, you must resolve in order of contacte. Find time of first collision, resolve, find time of next collision and resolve. OR accept the spungy collision resolution